# Multiple Calls to WCF service gives Bad Request 400 error in appcelerator

Tags: android, wcf, appcelerator

I have a project and in iPhone simulator it works perfect. However when I started testing on android device it gives strange behavior. It calls first WCF service and takes the result but for the second WCF service it gives 400 bad request. There is no problem in the Web service.

Is there any modification required in appcelerator setting in the code for particularly android?

Logs

```
[INFO] :   Alloy.Globals.switch_url=UserLogin
[ERROR] :  TiHTTPClient: (TiHttpClient-6) [1734,95811] HTTP Error (java.io.IOException): 400 : Bad Request
[ERROR] :  TiHTTPClient: java.io.IOException: 400 : Bad Request
[ERROR] :  TiHTTPClient:    at ti.modules.titanium.network.TiHTTPClient$ClientRunnable.run(TiHTTPClient.java:1216)
[ERROR] :  TiHTTPClient:    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

Comment: Check your ip of PC is accessible vai iphone or not.

Comment: It is accessible for example : I have 10 webservices that is called one by one. 1. Get cities is working smoothly and 2. Get Work places gives bad request.. So what i did is I removed the Get cities and called the Get Work places for first time it works smooth and 3. web service gives bad request

Comment: @obaid, are you sure that this log is related to your app code because I have similar logs in almost every project and it is never related to my app code and it's something related to titanium/android internally which never affects my app code and anything. Is your app not working or is it working properly just with above logs?

Comment: The above logs is coming when there is a second call to webservice. And my application is working but the 2nd call to web service is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution. You might probably using only one global xhr object

```
Alloy.Globals.xhr=Titanium.Network.createHTTPClient({async:true});
```

In Android I figured out that for every WCF/service request you need to initialize a new xhr object and send the request. This will work smoothly.